# What is the difference between fundus image, fundus photography and retinal image?

Tags: eye

I see these three terms in some papers in the field of medical images.

Google gives this kind of images for any of them, which indicates they pretty much mean the same thing.

[image]

Are they the same thing? Are they interchangeable?

Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fundus photography and fundus images are pictures of the retina. The [fundus](https://www.aao.org/eye-health/anatomy/fundus) of the eye is just the interior surface of the eye opposite the lens, so it includes the retina as well as the optic disc, macula, fovea, and posterior pole. In my reading, fundus cameras are also referred to as retinal cameras, and vice versa. "[Retinal imaging](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3131209/)" may be a more general term, as it may also include 3D optical coherence tomography and other imaging techniques that aren't necessarily photography.